# GAC - To add an assembly to the GAC, drag and drop works, but copy and paste doesn't? Why?

Tags: .net, drag-and-drop, gac, copy-paste

I would like to know why drag and drop works, and copy paste doesn't. What is happening with a drag and drop that isn't happening with a copy and paste?

Comment: Time to forget about this.  The shell extension isn't available for .NET 4.0 and the GAC is no longer at c:\windows\assembly

Comment: LOL Unfortunately I still support clients apps that are still 2.0 at this point. Good to know this isn't the same for 4.0 though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you drag and drop your assembly into `C:\windows\assembly` folder, it doesn't really get copied there—a special Windows Explorer plugin callis [`gacutil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.80).aspx) to install your assembly into GAC.

This Explorer plugin can be confusing because it may give one an illusion that GAC is just plain simple folder with lots of DLLs. **Actually, it is a hierarchical structure with a folder for each assembly name, inside of which there are folders for different versions, and so on.**

If you want to see the *real* GAC structure, open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion` in Windows Registry and set DWORD `DisableCacheViewer` to `1`. This will disable Cache Viewer plugin that makes GAC look so simple (but it also will make drag and drop to install unusable—you'll have to call `gacutil` yourself). Of course, you can use alternative file managers or console as well, if you don't want to mess with registry settings.

As for the reasons why copy-pasting does not work, I believe whoever designed Cache Viewer plugin thought that drag and drop is a good metaphor for *putting* something in GAC, whereas **implementing copying and pasting would really make GAC seem like a normal folder—which *it is not***.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan Abramov:
i added some thing more on that

Problem :Copy and paste is not working under assembly for install a new dll (C:\windows\assembly folder)

Ans:- you can see the folder architecture via changes the regedit entry through string "DisableCacheViewer" DWORD under  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion** make as it "1"

so you can see the folder view under the same .

and you can Dump all other assembly Dll through utility
Open a CMD and type below to use the Utility 
**for install**
"gacutil /i .dll"

**for UN-install**
"gacutil /u .dll"

if you need to **install/ Uninstall** more than one assembly so you can use

/il

and

/ul

option

best is that 
you can make a **batch file** and run under 
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin"** at once only

Thank you
 Ashutosh Soni